# DynamoDB, Check if Parent Exist before insert ,condition expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a single table design in AWS Dynamodb something like below with two GSI's

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| USER#Alex | USER#Alex |
|  | ORDER#1 |
|  | ORDER#2 |

So now if I do an insert item. With condition expression ensuring that User exist before adding an order. How do I go about checking attribute exist?

I try below and it fails. I know why after reading the article.

```
const putItemParams = {
  TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
  Item: {
    PK: {
      S: "USER#Alex",
    },
    SK: {
      S: "ORDER#1",
    },
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(PK)",
  },
};
```

After reading this article by @AlexDebrie
https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-condition-expressions/

I understand that Dynamodb looks for the Put Item key of the Item that is going to be written and checks if PK exists which in the above statement will be wrong. How do I fit in the logic.

I can think of transact items

```
transactWriteItems : [
  ConditionCheck : checkIf user exist with Pk:USER#Alex and SK:USER#Alex,
  Put :  Then do the put
]
```

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious.
If transactWriteItems is the only way then obvious disadvantage is that for my many put Items will turn into transactWriteItems with associated cost doubling since TransactWriteItems has double the RRU and WRU.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a (low cost) get-item to check if the user exists and if it does then do the order insert and if it doesn’t then do whatever appropriate?

This doesn’t seem like it has to be transactional.

Are you worried another process might delete the user while this one is trying to insert the order? Seems a weird design if so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to NoSql and DynamoDb. I was assuming the read check before put items might be an anti pattern. No I did not make it transactional worried about another process deleting. Rather wanted to have one write statement instead of reading and then writing in many parts in my application. By your answer, I assume its a usual practice to read and then write.

Comment: Thing is, items are independent of each other. So you can’t condition your write of one item on the existence of another item without doing transactions. Fine. But you don’t really need transaction guarantees. If the main user item exists it’s going to stay existing. Cheaper to avoid the txn. When you’re creating the user and order together, you may want a txn.